# avoid conflicting use paths, in rust

Tags: rust

I have a module `csv` and am trying to use the external `csv` library (`use csv::ReaderBuilder;`). I am getting a conflict.

### Minimal code that exhibits the error

```
mod csv {
    use ::csv::ReaderBuilder;
}
```

### Error message

```
 --> src/csv.rs:4:5
  |
4 | use csv::ReaderBuilder;
  |     ^^^ help: a similar path exists: `crate::csv`
  |
  = note: `use` statements changed in Rust 2018; read more at <https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html>
```

**My question is how do I avoid such conflicts?**
When creating a module, knowing the name of all modules that I may use via `use` seems un-reasonable. What am I doing wrong? I could name all my modules starting with `my_`, but this is ugly, and almost not the best solution.

---

Sorry if some of my terminology is wrong, I am new to rust.

Comment: By the way, I was only able to reproduce this particular error if you try to use `csv` from inside `csv.rs` (or other non-root module) and you *didn't have `csv` added as a dependency* in your `Cargo.toml`. If you add `csv = "1.1.6"` under the `[dependencies]` section, you shouldn't get this error.

Answer (score 2):

You can disambiguate these where you `use` them.  A leading `crate` path element indicates that the module belongs to the current crate.  A leading empty path element indicates that the module belongs to the namespace root, much like a leading `/` character makes a filesystem path absolute.

```
use ::csv::Foo;      // Uses Foo from the external csv crate
use crate::csv::Foo; // Uses Foo from the csv module of the current crate
```

Comment: I tried that, then read the manual. It suggested this solution as well. However, it did not work.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You're going to have to be more specific than "it did not work." Post code with the error message you get from the compiler.

Comment: It looks like I missed the dependency in the `Cargo.toml`. With that in place, it works as expected. Without it, the error message is not clear (very un-rust).

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor If it's the error message in your question, it looks pretty Rusty to me. It sees the problem and suggested a possible solution. It's not the right solution in this particular case, but Rust itself doesn't know what crates may or may not exist elsewhere. That's Cargo's responsibility.

Comment: Thanks, your answer helped. When I knew that I was doing that bit correct, it did not take long to find the problem. In future I need to realise that the help part is a suggestion, not a description of the problem.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Note in particular that the actual error message is _above_ the output you posted in your question. It should say something like `error[E0432]: unresolved import "..."` and then what follows is Rust trying to be helpful and provide more detail or a suggestion. Always start with the error, then read the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that I did not add the dependency to the `Cargo.toml` file.

On farther inspection, I see that the error message explains. However, I was confused by the help. It assumes that there is a syntax error in the `use` command.

In future I need to realise that the help part is a suggestion, not a description of the problem.